# export revit data to sql

Tags: sql, revit-api

I have some projects in Revit. when I export data to sql database of those projects, instead of adding records it overwrites previous records. how do I fix it. There is a single database where  records of all projects are to be saved

Comment: We would need more information to properly answer this. Can you show us how you export the data to the database?

Comment: @schmitsit, Thank you for your response. i export it via Link Revit Model with data base, select odbc, and so on.